# DSEFS Error: Not able to delete parquet file

Tags: python, linux, cassandra, parquet, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to overwrite a parquet file in a DSE File system through a python program, however, it runs into an error. I tried to manually delete the file through DSE FS by running a command:

rm -r "parquet_file_name"

This is the error I get:

Failed to remove directory '/work/test.parquet/_temporary/0/_temporary/': Failed to lock List(Lock(bb14d511-ddb0-11ec-a695-4d315fa7c835:_temporary)), possibly owned by Set(c8c79b72-ddb0-11ec-950b-8fef38ebaca8)
Failed to remove directory '/work/test.parquet/_temporary/0/': Directory not empty: /work/test.parquet/_temporary/0/
Failed to remove directory '/work/test.parquet/_temporary/': Directory not empty: /work/test.parquet/_temporary/
Failed to remove directory '/work/test.parquet/': Directory not empty: /work/test.parquet/

As a workaround, I am renaming the file in DSEFS and running my program again. Kindly help so that I don't have to rename the file again and again.

Answer (score 0):

This particular section of the error indicates that there are multiple threads operating on the directory:

```
... Failed to lock List(Lock(bb14d511-ddb0-11ec-a695-4d315fa7c835:_temporary)), \
  possibly owned by Set(c8c79b72-ddb0-11ec-950b-8fef38ebaca8) ...
```

That usually means that another process is still accessing the DSEFS directory when you tried to delete it. For what it's worth, those locks are time UUIDs so they contain timestamps for when they were created:

- `bb14d511-ddb0-11ec-a695-4d315fa7c835` = May 27, 2022 11:32:46 GMT
- `c8c79b72-ddb0-11ec-950b-8fef38ebaca8` = May 27, 2022 11:33:09 GMT

If you're still having issues, I recommend you log a ticket with [DataStax Support](https://support.datastax.com) so one of our engineers can troubleshoot it with you. Cheers!